# react-chessboard with chess.js uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chess

I am trying to implement react-chessboard with chess.js to my website so that I can evaluate a position that a user can create themselves, I am not trying to verify legal moves. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import {useState} from 'react';
import {Chessboard} from 'react-chessboard';
import {Chess} from 'chess.js';

const Board = () => {
    const [game, setGame] = useState(new Chess());

    const makeMove = (move) => {
        const gameCopy = {...game};
        gameCopy.move(move);
        setGame(gameCopy);
        return;
    }

    const onDrop = (startSquare, endSquare) => {
        makeMove({
            from: startSquare,
            to: endSquare,
        });
        return;
    }


  return <Chessboard position={game.fen()} onPieceDrop={onDrop} />;

}

export default Board;
```

When I try to make a move on the webpage it gives this error: Uncaught TypeError: gameCopy.move is not a function.

The code is straight from the react-chessboard documentation so I'm not sure why there is an error.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies for the example in react-chessboard show the chess.js version "^0.12.0", which you could install and the example would work as expected. At the time of writing this chess.js is on version "1.0.0-alpha.0", which presents the issue you described because the ongoing *game* is written as a class 'Chess', which you instantiate in the useState() definition. When you spread {...game} in gameCopy you lose the class methods and only retain the variables.

To integrate with the latest version of chess.js I would recommend using the loadPgn(pgn) or load(fen) methods to make a copy of the current game and use it to update state.

```
const Board = () => {
    const [game, setGame] = useState(new Chess());

    const makeMove = (move) => {
        const gameCopy = new Chess();
        gameCopy.loadPgn(game.pgn());
        gameCopy.move(move);
        setGame(gameCopy);
    }

    const onDrop = (startSquare, endSquare) => {
        makeMove({
            from: startSquare,
            to: endSquare,
        });
    }


  return <Chessboard position={fen} onPieceDrop={onDrop} />;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to differences in the chess.js library versions. The code below works in the current latest version at this time, 1.0.0-beta.6.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Chess } from "chess.js";
import { Chessboard } from "react-chessboard";

export default function Board() {
  const [game, setGame] = useState(new Chess());

  const makeMove = (move) => {
    game.move(move)
    setGame(new Chess(game.fen()))
  }

  function makeRandomMove() {
    const possibleMoves = game.moves();
    if (game.isGameOver() || game.isDraw() || possibleMoves.length === 0) return; // exit if the game is over
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleMoves.length);
    makeMove(possibleMoves[randomIndex]);
  }

  function onDrop(sourceSquare, targetSquare) {
    const move = makeMove({
      from: sourceSquare,
      to: targetSquare,
      promotion: "q", // always promote to a queen for example simplicity
    });

    // illegal move
    if (move === null) return false;
    setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 200);
    return true;
  }

  return(
     <div>
        <Chessboard position={game.fen()} onPieceDrop={onDrop} />
     </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it thinks that gameCopy.move is not a function, and you try to use it as such here: `gameCopy.move(move);`.

I am not familiar with the react-chessboard documentation, but have you made any changes to the code? Most often if you have such function it is either that you have not initiated a gameCopy, or you have forgotten to import something.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing chess.js incorrectly I believe

You're doing:

`import {Chess} from 'chess.js';`

The react-chessboard documentation shows:

`import Chess from "chess.js";`

Answer (score 0):

replace  `const gameCopy = {...game};`
with `const gameCopy = new Chess(game.fen());`

the Chess object can be instantiated with a fen string with above you are creating a new copy with current chess object